# getline undefined..... reading multiple lines

Tags: c++, getline

i have spent hours trying to get this to work and have been all over your website and nothing is working for me.....

basically i am working on a banking system for an assignment and this is the final thing that i need to do in order to complete my unit.

i am trying to read multiple lines from within a text file so i can output them. these will be my previous transactions.

i have managed to get it to store my values but i cannot, for the life of me, read the lines due to the fact that the "getline" code doesnt work. here is my code

```
static int linecount = 0 ;
ifstream readTransactions;
readTransactions.open("deposit");
string line ;
if ( readTransactions ) 
{
    while (getline (readTransactions , line ) ) {
    cout<<linecount<<": "<<line<<'\n';//supposing '\n' to be line end
    linecount++ ;
}
readTransactions.close( ) ;
return 0 ;
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? The code is unnecessarily verbose, but works for me (if you expect it to read and output each line of `"deposit"` if that file exists).

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Check if the file stream actually opened too.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/is_open/
is it open?

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to include the `string` header:

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: Why do you think that will make a difference? The first checks `failbit`, which will be set if the stream failed to open, and `badbit`. The second also checks the other status bits, but they won't be set anyway.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yeah, you're right. Just realized this. Thanks for pointing this out. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if ( readTransactions ) has no problem.
I want to know if 'reading multiple lines' means you see multiple lines are outputing on screen once. If yes, try endl instead of '\n'.

Comment: This will make no difference.

Comment: `endl` will just flush the stream after outputting `\n`. It might slow the program down, but won't change the output.